# Change PREFIX in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, allegrograph, topbraid-composer

I created an ontology with different prefixes (`rdf:`, `rdfs:`, `owl:`, `example:`, `car:`, `bike:`, ...). I use them to demarcate different domains and examples.

**A small extract:**

```
car:Software rdf:type demo:CyberObject.
car:Hardware rdf:type spdm:PhysicalObject.
car:Software car:hasMaturity "ten".
car:Hardware demo:isProducedIn loc:NorthPole.
```

**Is there any way to change a `PREFIX` "`car:`" to, e.g., "`plane:`", and keep the relations:**

```
plane:Software rdf:type demo:CyberObject.
plane:Hardware rdf:type spdm:PhysicalObject.
plane:Software plane:hasMaturity "ten".
plane:Hardware demo:isProducedIn loc:NorthPole.
```

I still need all the relations. The objects with `PREFIX` "`car:`" do not have to be replaced; it would be enough to create new ones with the new `PREFIX` and keep the old object in the database..

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 Update query doesn't work? replace the old URI with the new URI, or what exactly is here the problem?

Comment: The ontology already exists in the ontology editor/triple store. I just want to change prefixes of existing nodes @AKSW

Comment: I know what you wanted to do. But I don't see what you've tried so far...but know it doesn't matter, see the perfect answer of @StanislavKralin below (and accept it)

Comment: You've created *instance data*, not an ontology. An ontology is a structure of classes and attributes, which is used to describe entities. Your data describes entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace prefixes in subjects, predicates and objects successively.

```sql
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix car: <http://example.com/car/>
prefix demo: <http://example.com/demo/>
prefix spdm: <http://example.com/spdm/>
prefix loc: <http://example.com/loc/>
prefix plane: <http://example.com/plane/>

DELETE {?s ?p1 ?o} INSERT {?s ?p2 ?o} WHERE
{
?s ?p1 ?o .
FILTER (strstarts(str(?p1), str(car:)))
BIND (IRI(replace(str(?p1), str(car:), str(plane:)))  AS ?p2)
} ;

DELETE {?s1 ?p ?o} INSERT {?s2 ?p ?o} WHERE
{
?s1 ?p ?o .
FILTER (strstarts(str(?s1), str(car:)))
BIND (IRI(replace(str(?s1), str(car:), str(plane:)))  AS ?s2)
} ; 

DELETE {?s ?p ?o1} INSERT {?s ?p ?o2} WHERE
{
?s ?p ?o1 .
FILTER (strstarts(str(?o1), str(car:)) && isIRI(?o1))
BIND (IRI(replace(str(?o1), str(car:), str(plane:)))  AS ?o2)
} ;
```

Not tested in Allegrograph, and possibly there exist Allegrоgraph-specific solutions.

**Update**

> I still need all the relations, the objects with PREFIX "car" do not
>   have to be replaced…

Then do not replace prefixes in objects. However, keep in mind that an object in one triple can be a subject in another triple.

> …it would be enough to create new ones with the
>   new PREFIX and keep the old object in the database.

"Standalone" URIs are not stored in triplestore.